# Are really long story type questions ok?

Tags: discussion

I'm writing a murder mystery, and it's turning out to be a really long puzzle. As a reference, It's the length of this question: [Double whammy murder case! What happened?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/double-whammy-murder-case-what-happened), multiplied by ~3. Would the puzzle be too long to post on puzzling.se?

Unfortunately, it's a fairly complex puzzle and it would be impossible to reduce the length without severely damaging the quality and/or breaking the puzzle.

The story is in a story format, which contributes to the length, but (nearly) each part of the story brings something important to the puzzle, via a clue, or a red herring. What do I do? Should I finish it off and post it, or throw it out the window since it's too long to post anyways?

Comment: [Here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/the-pirates-of-beal-isle-very-long-logic-grid-puzzle)'s a recent puzzle which is extremely long yet seems well-received (+10/-1 so far).

Comment: That's almost as long as my new puzzle! Or roughly the same, didn't really run a comparison :P

Comment: Length sounds fine, but one potential problem to watch out for with long puzzles is if they're a narrative - a 'whodunnit' type of thing - then the problem is sometimes insufficiently well-defined. E.g. if the questioner tells a long story about the detective's day with loads of different details and the challenge is to pick out those details which the questioner thinks are relevant from those he/she thinks are irrelevant, and come up with the same murder scenario as the questioner has in their mind, then that tends towards being an exercise in attempted mind-reading rather than a good puzzle.

Comment: @AE not to worry, my murder mysteries are 100% logical, and if someone tries to fabricate any scenario other than the one I have in mind, the clues in the story will act as proof and dispel the theory.

Comment: @AE, I'd suggest that your comment is important enough to be posted as an answer when you have time. Even shorter puzzles with interesting story trappings can hang up solvers on inconsequential details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds fine. I don't see any problem with posting a really long mystery puzzle.

Comment: I just thought it might be too much of a reading job for the users, so I asked :P

Comment: Thanks for checking @Aify, but I don't see any problem here either.

Comment: There's no problem with a really short answer either :D